# SQL (big)query sequencial properties

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We have the denormalized data in bigquery:

```
User,   Cities Lived, Time,  Other properites
A       LD            1942
A       SF            1902
A       LA            2004
A       TK            2012
B       SF            1935
B       SD            1972
B       LA            1899
C       ...
```

What is the most efficient way to find the users that lived in SF before they lived in LA?

The output could be a list. In the above case, only "A" is listed.

It would be better if the list has both the date and the city:

```
A, 1902, SF, 2004, LA
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JOIN to compute the result you want:

```
SELECT la_table.user as user, la_table.city, la_table.time,  
  sf_table.city, sf_table.time 
FROM (
  SELECT user, time, city as la from yourTable where city = "LA") as la_table
JOIN EACH (
  SELECT user, time, city as la from yourTable where city = "SF") as sf_table
ON la_table.user = sf_table.user
WHERE la_table.time > sf_table.time
```

Note the "EACH" in the join clause, since the size of the tables are likely going to be large. See the BigQuery JOIN [reference](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#joins).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should join something like (pseudo code)
(SELECT TIME AS LA_TIME where Cities = LA GROUP BY User) and mark all rows where TIME_LA > TIME where city = SF. OUTPUT will be filtered by HAVING clausule on this "helping" column.

After last BQ update, you shouldn't be limited by size of output of nested select.